# Питон asyncio : можно ли определить async блока, а не функции?

Tags: python, asyncio

у меня есть обычная функция, внутри которой необходимо вызвать некоторый блок кода, который должен быть awaitable:

```py
def my_func():
    ....
    f=await do_stauff_1()
    a = f['id']
    await do_stuff_2(a)
    print("Done")
    return
```

Поскольку `my_func()` это обычная функция, я, естественно, должен свернуть эту await-часть в корутину `func()`, а внутри `my_func()` вызвать её как-нибудь так:

```py
asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(func())
```

Но таких вот `my_func()` у меня много и вырезание не больших кусков из каждой сильно загромождает код. Есть ли какая-то возможность определить эту часть кода как async, чтобы там внутри позволялся вызов awatable? Если бы awaitable был только один, то вопросов не было бы, но их в блоке как минимум два и второй вызов опирается, как видно, на результат работы первого.

Comment: эвент луп запущен?

Comment: Да, конечно. Мне пока пришлось создать корутину внутри my_func() и запустить ее через asyncio.ensure_future(). Не знаю, единственное ли это решение.

Comment: в питоне есть `callback based api` и `async/await`. Перейти из async/await к колбэкам легко, а вот из колбэков к await никак у меня не получается не завершив вызванную функцию. только если луп запущен в другом треде.

а так получаешь или выполнение таска только после завершения функции или ошибку луп уже запущен.